# Binding a buffer to multiple targets

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Can I bind a opengl buffer object to multiple targets. For instance, I bind a buffer to the target array buffer and then bind the same buffer to SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER or some otger target, is the buffer bound to the first second or both targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL specifications:

> `void [gl]BindBuffer( enum target, uint buffer );` If the buffer object
>   named *buffer* has not been previously bound, the GL creates a new state
>   vector, initialized with a zero-sized memory buffer and comprising all
>   the state and with the same initial values listed in table...

And

> BindBuffer may also be used to bind an existing buffer object. If the
>   bind is successful no change is made to the state of the newly bound
>   buffer object, and **any previous binding to target is broken**.

So, yes: you can use the same name (as created with `glGenBuffers`) and bind this existing bound buffer with a different use (*target* in OpenGL parlance). But I can't think of a reason to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason I want to do this is that in my program I want to be able to attach a buffer to a VAO using ARRAY ELEMENT BUFFER. This in effect will 'create a IBO' attached to the VBO. Then if I later wanted to edit the IBO, I could bind it to ARRAY BUFFER and not have to worry about un-attaxhing it from the VAO. The question is whether or not binding the buffer to ARRAY BUFFER will un-attach the buffer from the VAO it is bound to.

Comment: Binding to ARRAY BUFFER when it was ARRAY ELEMENT BUFFER before will break the previous binding. If your reason is changing data, why not use  `glBufferSubData` without any un-attaching?

Comment: @Ripi2: "*will break the previous binding*" It will break the previous `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target binding, like you quoted the spec. But it won't change any other binding locations for that buffer.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Thanks for the help.